# R: Updating Time Series plot with dropdown selection

Tags: r, r-markdown, r-plotly, r-highcharter

My data data represents monthly sales of 3 different product (A,B and C) from 2018

```
structure(list(Time = c("January 2018", "January 2018", "January 2018", 
"February 2018", "February 2018", "February 2018", "March 2018", 
"March 2018", "March 2018", "April 2018", "April 2018", "April 2018", 
"May 2018", "May 2018", "May 2018", "June 2018", "June 2018", 
"June 2018", "July 2018", "July 2018", "July 2018", "August 2018", 
"August 2018", "August 2018", "September 2018", "September 2018", 
"September 2018", "October 2018", "October 2018", "October 2018", 
"November 2018", "November 2018", "November 2018", "December 2018", 
"December 2018", "December 2018", "January 2019", "January 2019", 
"January 2019", "February 2019", "February 2019", "February 2019", 
"March 2019", "March 2019", "March 2019", "April 2019", "April 2019", 
"April 2019", "May 2019", "May 2019", "May 2019", "June 2019", 
"June 2019", "June 2019", "July 2019", "July 2019", "July 2019", 
"August 2019", "August 2019", "August 2019", "September 2019", 
"September 2019", "September 2019", "October 2019", "October 2019", 
"October 2019", "November 2019", "November 2019", "November 2019", 
"December 2019", "December 2019", "December 2019", "January 2020", 
"January 2020", "January 2020", "February 2020", "February 2020", 
"February 2020", "March 2020", "March 2020", "March 2020", "April 2020", 
"April 2020", "April 2020", "May 2020", "May 2020", "May 2020", 
"June 2020", "June 2020", "June 2020", "July 2020", "July 2020", 
"July 2020", "August 2020", "August 2020", "August 2020", "September 2020", 
"September 2020", "September 2020", "October 2020", "October 2020", 
"October 2020", "November 2020", "November 2020", "November 2020", 
"December 2020", "December 2020", "December 2020"), Category = c("A", 
"B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", 
"C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", 
"A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", 
"B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", 
"C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", 
"A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", 
"B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", 
"C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", 
"A", "B", "C"), Sales = c(10222332, 7942779, 725555250, 6375699, 
2875550, 440631801, 8864571, 12334681, 629036931, 7473920, 9161918, 
659864891, 10047537, 8466945, 687218719, 8980204, 9829918, 612005973, 
10301078, 8539884, 626423889, 11668052, 9367543, 652252806, 10374909, 
7755942, 543875760, 14635624, 4343942, 561692585, 13560795, 5791480, 
532812769, 12662526, 3759661, 555013915, 15786646, 3853641, 626093690, 
9505737, 5993417, 351970315, 16938873, 13168685, 600298206, 10827490, 
10334899, 723990224, 14967314, 7270579, 631821347, 14495324, 
6507689, 533818484, 13449295, 7678789, 535126612, 17214970, 5880437, 
564680477, 12970874, 4965748, 557062440, 15750730, 8085819, 600121430, 
18948080, 6057461, 592022480, 16238799, 6148273, 629364277, 12143876, 
4314784, 451238348, 5354879, 5703890, 460174095, 5430258, 5204303, 
670928810, 7591477, 7459831, 636383634, 5387797, 8551921, 535302293, 
7103341, 8104402, 518039675, 7411340, 9247334, 466740767, 7815582, 
8410930, 554147105, 9270913, 7991272, 539793655, 13351559, 8675692, 
559303077, 10258273, 6158217, 550218658, 11708049, 13333011, 
578068296)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -108L), groups = structure(list(Time = c("April 2018", 
"April 2018", "April 2018", "April 2019", "April 2019", "April 2019", 
"April 2020", "April 2020", "April 2020", "August 2018", "August 2018", 
"August 2018", "August 2019", "August 2019", "August 2019", "August 2020", 
"August 2020", "August 2020", "December 2018", "December 2018", 
"December 2018", "December 2019", "December 2019", "December 2019", 
"December 2020", "December 2020", "December 2020", "February 2018", 
"February 2018", "February 2018", "February 2019", "February 2019", 
"February 2019", "February 2020", "February 2020", "February 2020", 
"January 2018", "January 2018", "January 2018", "January 2019", 
"January 2019", "January 2019", "January 2020", "January 2020", 
"January 2020", "July 2018", "July 2018", "July 2018", "July 2019", 
"July 2019", "July 2019", "July 2020", "July 2020", "July 2020", 
"June 2018", "June 2018", "June 2018", "June 2019", "June 2019", 
"June 2019", "June 2020", "June 2020", "June 2020", "March 2018", 
"March 2018", "March 2018", "March 2019", "March 2019", "March 2019", 
"March 2020", "March 2020", "March 2020", "May 2018", "May 2018", 
"May 2018", "May 2019", "May 2019", "May 2019", "May 2020", "May 2020", 
"May 2020", "November 2018", "November 2018", "November 2018", 
"November 2019", "November 2019", "November 2019", "November 2020", 
"November 2020", "November 2020", "October 2018", "October 2018", 
"October 2018", "October 2019", "October 2019", "October 2019", 
"October 2020", "October 2020", "October 2020", "September 2018", 
"September 2018", "September 2018", "September 2019", "September 2019", 
"September 2019", "September 2020", "September 2020", "September 2020"
), Category = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", 
"A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", 
"B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", 
"C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", 
"A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", 
"B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", 
"C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", 
"A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", 
"B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C"), .rows = structure(list(
    10L, 11L, 12L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 
    58L, 59L, 60L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 
    106L, 107L, 108L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 
    1L, 2L, 3L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 
    55L, 56L, 57L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 
    88L, 89L, 90L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 
    13L, 14L, 15L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 
    67L, 68L, 69L, 103L, 104L, 105L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 64L, 65L, 
    66L, 100L, 101L, 102L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 97L, 
    98L, 99L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -108L), .drop = TRUE))
```

```
1     January 2018        A  10222332
2     January 2018        B   7942779
.....................................
106  December 2020        A  11708049
107  December 2020        B  13333011
108  December 2020        C 578068296
```

Now I want to do time series decomposition using `stl()` function. So I subset category 'A' and put it into the function

```
library(tidyverse)
library(highcharter)

# Subset data for category A
df.A <- subset(data, Category =="A")

#convert data into Time series
TS.A <- ts(df.A$Sales, frequency = 12, start = c(2018, 1))

TS.A <- TS.A %>%
  stl(s.window="periodic", robust=TRUE)`

hchart(TS.A)
```

[image]

Now I want to create an RMarkdown with dynamic plots. So instead of subseting each Category (A,B,C) separetely, let user choose it from the drop-down list and adapt output according to chosen input. I know it is possible in [shiny](/questions/tagged/shiny), but I want to somehow implement this dynamic plot into  Html (rmarkdown) document. Something like this:

[image]

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71353287/user-inputs-for-r-ggplot-or-plotly-without-shiny/71427299#71427299) you can find a related answer.  Please also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40024029/plotly-updating-data-with-dropdown-selection).

Comment: The problem is that I have never used java language, so I really don't know it

Comment: When using [dropdowns in r-plotly](https://plotly.com/r/dropdowns/) there is no additional JS required.

Comment: FYI - If using an rmd with `runtime: shiny` you won't be able to have a standalone html document. Shiny requires a 'server.R' file in order to run the reactiveness. So whoever uses that doc would either need to have R installed or you could host it on ShinyServer / ShinyApps.io

[More info here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/interactive-docs.html#:~:text=click%20%E2%80%9CRun%20Document.%E2%80%9D-,The,-structure%20of%20an)